# how to send data from html to node js?

Tags: jquery, node.js, nodes, node-modules

Folling is my code of `html` from where I am send the data through JQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        sndt();
        function sndt(nid){
        $.ajax({
          url:"localhost:3000/client",
          method:"POST",
          data:{nid,test:"dooo"},
          success:function(data){
              $("#video").html(data);
      },
      error:function(data){
        console.log("ZUBAIR");
      }
        })
      }
      })
</script>
```

Now I want to display this test data in my node js console here is my code in node js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var cons = require('consolidate'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'www'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; // signalingServerPort
var localHost = "http://localhost:" + PORT; // http
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "www")));
// Remove trailing slashes in url
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.substr(-1) === "/" && req.path.length > 1) {
    let query = req.url.slice(req.path.length);
    res.redirect(301, req.path.slice(0, -1) + query);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
// no room name specified to join
app.get("/join/", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/");
});
// join to room
app.post("/join/*", function (req, res) {
  var t = (req.body.test);
  console.log("ttttt"+ t);
  if (Object.keys(req.query).length > 0) {
    console.log("redirect:" + req.url + " to " + url.parse(req.url).pathname);
    res.redirect(url.parse(req.url).pathname);
  } else {
    var t = (req.body.test);
  console.log("ttttt"+ t);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "www/client.html"));
  }
});
```

those are the error which I am facing

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/client' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

and

`jquery-2.2.4.js:9175 POST localhost:3000/client net::ERR_FAILED`

this is my node js code get where I am going wrong??thanks?

Answer (score 0):

This is a cors issue when you call from frontend to backend, you have to enable cors in backend code

So you need to first install cors by running the following command

```
npm install cors
```

After installation then go in node js code and import cors and use cors as I used the following code

```
  var cors = require('cors')
        var app = express()
        
        app.use(cors())
```

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000?uuu=43683CleanCake' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

Comment: and please guide me about this `jquery-2.2.4.js:9175 POST localhost:3000/client net::ERR_FAILED` why I am getting this error